# Xquery: Dividing the attribute value by spaces

Tags: xpath, xquery, database, xpath-2.0

So I'm trying to get the country codes of this river.

```
<river id="river-Donau" country="SRB A D H HR SK BG RO MD UA">
</river>
```

How can I access them individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This splits the attribute at all whitespace, allowing multiple following each other, and returns them as a sequence:

```
//@country/tokenize(., '\s+')
```